# How to know the number of transactions sent to an address?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, nodejs

Ethereum assign random nonces to contract transacctions?
I am trying to send my transacctions with web3js assigning a correlative nonce.
I read the last nonce and increment it in one to send the tranx.

The problem is that sometimes, ethereum assign random nonces to other tranxs  (sent by holders with a wallet for ex) that I dont sent with my web3js dapp.

Then, when my Dapp send tranxs cant control the correlative nonces and EVM return errors.

How could I control nonce count?
How could I know the biggest nonce in my contract tranxs sent to avoid errors?

**EDIT:**
This web3js function return the number of transactions sent from an address. Exists a method to know the number of transactions sent to an address?

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount()
```